# Conjecture a formula for the nth term of the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I am struggling with finding any formula that fits this sequence, please help.

- an=1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1

Comment: Any particular reason why

$$a_n = \begin{cases} 0 & n \text{ is a multiple of } 3 \\ 1 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

isn't suitable? Any formula otherwise would just be a fancier way of saying the same.

Comment: Well I am tasked to find a recursive formula of an explicit formula. That is where my struggle is.

Comment: This:  $$a_n = n^2\pmod 3$$

Comment: This is the best I could find $$a_n=n^2-3 \left\lfloor \frac{n^2}{3}\right\rfloor$$ using the floor function

Comment: If you want a recursion, try $a_n = 2 - a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after thinking and trying different combinations. I got this:

$\boxed{a_n = ( \omega^n + \omega^{2n} ) - (-1)^{\omega^n + \omega^{2n}}\times2}$

Where $\omega$ is the imaginary cube root of unity.

This is based on the fact that,

$\omega^n + \omega^{2n} = \begin{cases}
 2&\text{if n is a multiple of 3}\, \\
 -1&\text{otherwise}\ \\
\end{cases}$

$\implies a_n = \begin{cases}
 (2) - (-1)^{2}\times 2&\text{if n is a multiple of 3}\, \\
 (-1) - (-1)^{-1}\times 2&\text{otherwise}\ \\
\end{cases}$

$\implies a_n = \begin{cases}
 (2) - 2&\text{if n is a multiple of 3}\, \\
 (-1) + 2&\text{otherwise}\ \\
\end{cases}$

$\implies a_n = \begin{cases}
 0&\text{if n is a multiple of 3}\, \\
 1&\text{otherwise}\ \\
\end{cases}$